# How to display data in an sqlplus table in an orderly manner

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle19c

I selected every details customers tables in the Order Entry Schema but my data isn't ordered. How do i make the table presentable making every column and row clear to read and understand

I used the query select * from oe.customers and below is how my data was retrieved and makes it quite difficult to read.

```
CUSTOMER_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME      CUST_LAST_NAME
----------- -------------------- --------------------
CUST_ADDRESS(STREET_ADDRESS, POSTAL_CODE, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, COUNTRY_ID)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE_NUMBERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NLS NLS_TERRITORY                  CREDIT_LIMIT
--- ------------------------------ ------------
CUST_EMAIL                               ACCOUNT_MGR_ID
---------------------------------------- --------------
CUST_GEO_LOCATION(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATE_OF_B MARITAL_STATUS       G INCOME_LEVEL
--------- -------------------- - --------------------
25-MAY-44 single               F A: Below 30,000

CUSTOMER_ID CUST_FIRST_NAME      CUST_LAST_NAME
----------- -------------------- --------------------
CUST_ADDRESS(STREET_ADDRESS, POSTAL_CODE, CITY, STATE_PROVINCE, COUNTRY_ID)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHONE_NUMBERS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NLS NLS_TERRITORY                  CREDIT_LIMIT
--- ------------------------------ ------------
CUST_EMAIL                               ACCOUNT_MGR_ID
---------------------------------------- --------------
CUST_GEO_LOCATION(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DATE_OF_B MARITAL_STATUS       G INCOME_LEVEL
--------- -------------------- - --------------------
```

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i6ne.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you're just running ad hoc queries, you probably don't want to be using `SQL*Plus`.  You're almost certainly better off downloading SQL Developer which is an actual GUI that presents query output in a nice, GUI fashion.

`SQL*Plus` was designed back in a time when reporting generally meant generating fixed width output that would get spooled to a physical printer every morning and generate hundreds of pages of output on green bar paper that would get distributed to various humans in the company to review.  So you need to think like an old school report developer.

First, you need to figure out how wide your output window is and set your linesize appropriately.  If your output window is, say, 120 characters wide, you'd start with

```
set linesize 120
```

Now, you have to figure out how much space out of those 120 character that you want to give each column of your output knowing that larger string values will wrap within the column.  So if you want to allow 15 characters for the customer first and last name

```
column cust_first_name format a15;
column cust_last_name format a15;
```

You'd need to do that for each column you're outputting.  Realistically, it probably doesn't make sense to select a geographic location from `SQL*Plus`, you'd want to select components of that composite object.